# git pull to a specific folder, not the home folder

Tags: git

When I `git pull` repository info, all of my repository folders end up in my user's root folder. Instead, I want git to pull each repository into a folder with the repository name, but inside my a folder called `git-repositories` in the root of my user.

I tried `cd`'ing into `~/git-repositories/blogger-templates` (blogger-templates is the repo name) and then running

```
git pull https://github.com/blue-ice/blogger-templates
```

but all of the folders from the repository ended up in my root folder instead. How can I make them go into `~/git-repositories/blogger-templates`?

Comment: Are you doing  *git clone* first?

Comment: Nope. What should I do with `git clone`?

Comment: I provided an answer below.  The first step in using a GitHub repo is `git clone`.  After the initial `git clone`, your `git pull` will work as expected.

Comment: Did `git clone` fix it?  I'm trying to think of some other reasons why your problem would occur ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the github repo web page at:

```
https://github.com/blue-ice/blogger-templates
```

On the right sidebar, you'll see this:

```
SSH Clone URL
git@github.com:blue-ice/blogger-templates.git
```

The first time you retrieve a repository from GitHub, you want to use `git clone`

```
git clone git@github.com:blue-ice/blogger-templates.git
```

After the initial `git clone`, you can use `git pull` and things will behave as you expect.

Comment: Yup, using ssh helped me out. Also, using relative addresses when `git add`'ing files helped make the folders update correctly for some reason. Thanks for the answer, and now I have a good workflow set out at https://gist.github.com/blue-ice/4a94fc06859dd9f1b586 . Again, thanks for the help. It's fun to learn new things :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you 've made/cloned a repo in your home dir. Run `git clone url_to_remote path_where_you_want_your_local`. Now `git pull` will update files in the path you provided in the second argument (note that you have to be inside the local repo dir to pull). Also it would be good to remove .git dir from your home.